# cannot convert expression type void to type integer in Swift using XCTAssertEqual

Tags: swift, ios8, assert

I am very new to the Swift language and XCode. Have a error message from this code:

**Class Deck**

```
class Deck {

    var decks : Integer = 0

    init () {
       decks = 1
    }

    init (amountOfDecks : Integer){
       decks = amountOfDecks
    }

    func getAmountOfCards() -> Integer {
        return 0
    }

}
```

**Test Class**

```
import XCTest
import helloWorldv2

class helloWorldv2Tests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testDeckConstructor() {
        var deck = Deck(amountOfDecks: 1)
        var amount : Integer = deck.getAmountOfCards()
        let expected : Integer = 52

        // ERROR: Cannot convert the expression type 'void' to type 'integer'
        XCTAssertEqual(expected, amount)
    }        
}
```

I set the two variables to type Integer so don't understand why I cant compare the two values...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. the Type you should be using is `Int` (`Integer` is a protocol, not a Type, and there is not an implementation in Swift for `==` that accepts arguments conforming to the `Integer` protocol)
2. specifying the Type in the way that you are doing it is unnecessary, thanks to Swift's "type inference" - when you declare and assign a value to a variable, it will automatically give that variable the same Type as the value that is being assigned to it (and literal integers in Swift are typed as `Int` by default)... so `let expected = 52` will automatically give your `expected` constant the Type `Int` without you having to declare it as such

Answer (score 0):

`Integer` is a protocol, you should use `Int` instead as that is an actual struct.